# How to show id and name in toast after clicking per button

Tags: android, listview

I am unable to Toast every id and name after clicking button. Every time last id and name are showing after clicking different button. I want to show every list of data in Toast after clicking specific button

[image: Screenshot]

Activity

```
public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView studentListView;
    ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    StudentAdapter studentAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        studentListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.studentListView);
        studentList.add(new Student(01, "Monir"));
        studentList.add(new Student(02, "Jibon"));
        studentList.add(new Student(03, "Mahmud"));
        studentList.add(new Student(04, "Saiful"));
        studentList.add(new Student(05, "Arif"));

        studentAdapter = new StudentAdapter(this, studentList);
        studentListView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);

    }

    public void viewStudentClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),studentAdapter.nameText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),studentAdapter.idText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class StudentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Student> {

    private Activity context;
    private ArrayList<Student> students;
    TextView idText;
    TextView nameText;

    public StudentAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Student> student) {
        super(context, R.layout.student_info, student);
        this.context = context;
        this.students = student;
    }

    //Array Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent){

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.student_info, parent, false);
        idText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idText);
        nameText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);

        idText.setText(students.get(position).getId()+"");
        nameText.setText(String.valueOf(students.get(position).getName()));

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you calling viewStudentClick()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

            studentListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.studentListView);
            studentList.add(new Student(01, "Monir"));
            studentList.add(new Student(02, "Jibon"));
            studentList.add(new Student(03, "Mahmud"));
            studentList.add(new Student(04, "Saiful"));
            studentList.add(new Student(05, "Arif"));

            studentAdapter = new StudentAdapter(this, studentList);
            studentListView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);
            studentListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(ListViewActivity.this,studentList.get(position).getId() +
                            studentList.get(position).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        }
```

Comment: remove viewStudentClick and try this.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
studentListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    // selected item
    String name = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Position:"+position+", Name: "+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
});
```